# How do I change the scale of my axes and transform the coordinate system for my plot using matplotlib, while keeping the figure the same?

Tags: matplotlib

I started learning matplotlib, and tried to plot a heatmap for my dataset. The plot is goo, but I want to change the scale of my axes and transform the coordinates without it affecting the figure.
[image: My Graph]
I want the 0 to 100 to be 13 to 14 on the X-Axis and 14.5 to 15.5 on the Y-Axis.
Code which I am currently implementing -

```
plt.matshow(dataslice, interpolation="nearest")
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Longitude")
plt.ylabel("Latitude")
plt.savefig(f"{file_name}_Data.png")
```

I want to keep the figure the same, but want to change my axes scales and shift the origin.

I tried using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` but I wasn't able to produce the same heatmap this way.

Edit 1 - dataslice is a 2-D Numpy Array. The graph plots 10000 discrete points with range of X being (13 to 14) and range of Y being (14.5 to 15.5).

Comment: What is `dataslice`? A numpy array?

Comment: Also, where do those values come from (the 13 to 14 and 14.5 to 15.5)?

Comment: Edited the question as well. Yes `dataslice` is a numpy array and the values are from my dataset. Basically I have 10000 discrete points with x between 13 and 14 and y between 14.5 and 15.5.

Comment: Where are those x and y values being stored?

Comment: At the moment not storing them anywhere just using the Indices for the Numpy Array to get value of x and y that point corresponds to. `dataslice` is 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided very much information about what you do and don't have. That said, I think I might understand enough. To ensure your plot has the proper coordinates, you can use [`plt.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) which can be given the x and y values (either as 1D arrays or meshgrids) along with the data to be plotted at those points. You will want to generate the x and y arrays more algorithmically than I show below, but once you have them you should be able to do this:

```py
x = np.linspace(13, 14, dataslice.shape[0])
y = np.linspace(14.5, 15.5, dataslice.shape[1])
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, dataslice)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, did work. Will try to be more informative in future questions.
Thanks again.

Comment: @AbirAbhyankar it takes some work to write a good and complete question. Just be ready to address comments.